# Откуда идут проценты в line-height? CSS

Tags: css

Не совсем понимаю CSS правила, откуда идут проценты в данном случае?

```
line-height: 150%
```

Извините если я не совсем понятно написал

Полный код:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Impact;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
}

p {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 150%;
}

img {
  max-width: 80%;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.img-description {
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 20px 0 40px 0;
}

ul {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 150%;
}


/* ---------------------Шрифт--------------------- */

.text-red {
  color: red;
}

.text-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>K-129</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <article>
      <h1>K-129</h1>
      <p>
        Б-103, К-129 — советская <span class="text-red">дизель-электрическая подводная лодка</span> проекта 629А. Основное вооружение — ракетный комплекс Д-4 с тремя баллистическими ракетами Р-21 в ограждении рубки (первая советская БРПЛ подводного старта).
        Входила в состав Тихоокеанского флота СССР. Командир — капитан первого ранга В. И. Кобзарь.
      </p>
      <img src="./images/Soviet_ballistic_missile_submarine_K-129.jpg" alt="подводная лодка">
      <p class="img-description">Подводная лодка. Номера меняли перед каждым походом</p>
      <p>Затонула приблизительно 7—8 марта 1968 года в северной части Тихого океана, в точке с координатами 40°06′ с. ш. 179°57′ з. д.HGЯO, на глубине порядка 5600 м. Погиб весь экипаж в составе 98 человек. 12 августа 1974 года в результате секретной операции
        ЦРУ <span class="text-red text-bold">«Проект
                        Азориан»</span>, при помощи специально сконструированного оборудования (корабль «Гломар Эксплорер» и спецдок с устройством подводного захвата корпуса лодки), была поднята носовая часть подводной лодки.</p>
      <img src="./images/Golf_II_class_SSB_629A_project.svg.png" alt="golf">
      <p class="img-description">Гольф 2 - схема</p>
      <h2>В массовой культуре</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>В документальном сериале <span class="text-red">«Жизнь после людей»</span> в одной из серий рассказывается об останках подлодки К-129 и баллистических ракетах Р-21, которые не были подняты на поверхность американцами. Через 25 лет после исчезновения
          человечества корпус ракет проржавеет, и туда проникнет вода, что вызовет химические реакции с литием и приведёт к мощному взрыву. Несмотря на то, что толща воды погасит ударную волну, от радиации может умереть мгновенно всё живое в радиусе одного
          километра.</li>
        <li>В документальном сериале «Равновесие страха. Война, которая осталась холодной» подробно рассказано о походе <span class="text-red text-bold">К-129</span>, операции по её подъему и похоронах 6 членов экипажа, которых удалось найти.</li>
        <li>В фантастическом романе Чарльза Стросса «Дженнифер Морг» из цикла «Досье Прачечной» на подводной лодке находилась новейшая на тот момент оккультная технология СССР. В ходе операции «Дженнифер» подлодку не удалось поднять со дна, потому что это
          нарушало дипломатическое соглашение с Глубинными, которым угрожало использование данной технологии, и они отломили большую часть при попытке подъёма.</li>
      </ul>
    </article>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Проценты идут от размера шрифта, если его размер равен, например, `16px` то:

```
div {
  line-height: 1;
  // высота равна 16px
}

// или

div {
  line-height: 100%;
  // высота равна 16px
}
```

соответственно если значение `line-height` равно `150`% (или `1.5`), то высота должна быть `24px` (может чуть отличаться в зависимости от шрифта, браузера и т.п).

*Размеры и их взаимоотношения можно посмотреть открыв вкладку `computed` в инструментах разработчика Вашего браузера.*